# Who to battle when first able to access gyms?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm level 6. All the gyms I find are held by players between level 21 and 24. How can I find someone of my level to battle, because it's not enjoyable to go up against these gyms - nor am I learning how to battle this way.

Comment: Good question, but I'm not sure there's a good answer for it. Are you able to beat even just one Pokemon in these gyms, given you're able to use 6 against it? If so, you could take down a gym eventually - although granted it will take some time.

Comment: get a friend to help, learn to dodge attacks and you'll be fine

Comment: You could practice by training at gyms that belong to your team.

Comment: I wouldn't go for gyms at all until you're level 2x. - Or at least not spend any Stardust.

Comment: Also if you have a possibility to travel to a smaller town/village, consider battling there. Players there have lower levels than those in big cites, so conquering the gyms should be easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately due to the design of the game, people who start late are going to be at a massive disadvantage when taking gyms as the higher level players would be constantly taking them with high CP Pokemon.

It's likely going to be impossible for you to get 10 gyms until you get to a much higher level where you have access to higher CP pokemon. Due to the fact that the xp required to level increases by an insane amount at around level 20 and beyond, you could catch up somewhat. At around 20 - 25 you should be strong enough to defeat a level 2 or 3 gym easily by yourself.

Some things you can do to level the playing field at a low level is to consider the types of pokemon. You will want a Pokemon that takes reduced damage and deals extra damage to the ones in the gym. You can beat pokemon up to double your CP in this way.

Another thing to consider is dodging. Dodge when the yellow sparks appear and you can reduce or completely negate the damage dealt by the enemy pokemon. This makes it easier to defeat higher pokemon.

The final piece of advice is to team up with a friend or two. I've found that all gyms are pretty easy when it's 2v1 (total of like 12 v 2 or 3) as you are effectively doubling your attack (it also doubles your HP and the enemy's attack, but these two cancel out essentially, or you can dodge to negate the attack as explained previously).

Answer (score 0):

There is no facility to battle within your level range. Though it is possible to win battles eventually if you persist.